# per http request over per tcp connection

Tags: go

My question is simple: How many http requests make how many tcp connections to server in Go.

I'm coding a tool can send many http requests, but I find all this requests over one or two tcp connetions, seem like golang http Transport have a connections pool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `DefaultTransport` for your HTTP requests then the TCP connections are reused.

> DefaultTransport is the default implementation of Transport and is used by DefaultClient. It establishes network connections as needed and caches them for reuse by subsequent calls.

You can use `MaxConnsPerHost` to limit the total number of connections:

```
// MaxConnsPerHost optionally limits the total number of
// connections per host, including connections in the dialing,
// active, and idle states. On limit violation, dials will block.
//
// Zero means no limit.
//
// For HTTP/2, this currently only controls the number of new
// connections being created at a time, instead of the total
// number. In practice, hosts using HTTP/2 only have about one
// idle connection, though.
MaxConnsPerHost int
```

**Edit**

I highly suggest you read the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) as Go has one of the most well documented standard library. Anyway, you can configure `http.Transport` to disable keep-alive to force usage of one TCP connection per request.

```
// DisableKeepAlives, if true, disables HTTP keep-alives and
// will only use the connection to the server for a single
// HTTP request.
//
// This is unrelated to the similarly named TCP keep-alives.
DisableKeepAlives bool
```

Comment: Which, as I would like to point out, makes sense: a [three-way tcp handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) is _expensive_ time wise .

Comment: Sorry, i wanna to make established for every http request, not  reuse TCP connections. Any way to reach that?

Comment: As stated in my edit, set `DisableKeepAlives` to `true`.